# The arctangent is equal to an integral of functions up to a multiple of $2\pi$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, logarithms

Let $a,b:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ be $C^1$ functions such that $a^2+b^2>0$ everywhere. Prove that
$$
\int_0^{\Omega} \frac{ab'-a'b}{a^2+b^2} dx = arg(a+\text ib)(\Omega) + 2\pi k(\Omega)  
$$
where $k(\Omega)\in \mathbb Z$ for every $\Omega$.

Obviously, if $a\ne 0$ everywhere, then one can recognize the derivative of the $\arctan$ function inside of the integral. One can argue in similar ways if $b\ne 0$ everywhere. How can I proceed in the other cases?

NOTE that this comes from the problem of evaluating $\exp(\int \psi'/\psi)$, where $\psi = a+ib$, and proving it is a constant multiple of $\psi$ itself, so the solution MUST NOT go back there, nor use properties of the complex logarithm, thanks.

Comment: @geetha290krm You might note that $\arg(a+ib)$ is just another way to write $\arctan(b/a)$.

Comment: Show that $(x,y) \mapsto \arg(x + iy)$ is a well-defined C^1 function everywhere except on the positive or negative real line (depending on exactly how you want to define it), where it jumps in value by $2\pi$. Note that the derivative of $\arg(a + bi)$ is still your integrand. Note that the definitions of the positive and negative real axis versions of the arg function differ from each other by $\pi$ always. Note that if $a+bi$ is on the positive real axis, then there is some neighborhood where it does not cross the negative real axis.